# How to load a registry free COM dll in plugin dll which is loaded by third party application?

Tags: c#, c++, regfreecom

I have got the registry free COM working with a sample application following the steps given here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx[^]

Now I need to load the same reg free COM from a dll and not from an application directly. I tried making a manifest file for a dll, but it can't find the dll. Is that possible to change the application maniest to assembly manifest of my plugin dll and load reg free COM from there?

I didn't find much information on this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to define this at the DLL level. I've run into a similar issue at work and didn't find an acceptable solution other than just modify the manifest of the calling executable.

Comment: I know, that's the only way so far. But my concern is whether it is a recommended solution to modify the application manifest while deploying this on the customers machine. How did you achieve this?

Comment: We had full control over both the exe and dll as they were packaged together, so we just bundled an appropriate manifest. I didn't like the solution, but we didn't have time to investigate anything better. Good luck finding a solution for your situation.